# join using linq getting error

Tags: c#, linq

Getting error while joining two tables using linq , the error is `The name 'u' does not exist in the current context`

Here is my Code

```
from t in Teams
join u in Users on t.TeamId equals u.TeamId  into g
where (t.TeamName.Contains("Pr"))  && (t.Deleted != true) ||(u.FirstName.Contains("Ch"))
select new { t.TeamId,t.TeamName, t.Description,UserId=g.Count()}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be referencing `g`, not `u` since you joined into `g`?

Comment: The UserID section in the select could be misleading as you're returning a count not an ID. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed it to do the join first, then filter on where and then group. Hopefully this works:

```
from t in Teams
join u in Users on t.TeamId equals u.TeamId
where (t.TeamName.Contains("Pr")) && (t.Deleted != true) || (u.FirstName.Contains("Ch"))
group new { t.TeamId, t.TeamName, t.Description } by new { t.TeamId, t.TeamName, t.Description } into g
select new { g.Key.TeamId, g.Key.TeamName, g.Key.Description, UserId = g.Count() };
```